# SQL взять значение одного столбца, если второй пустой

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

в таблице customer есть поля name и lastname, необходимо взять значение столбца name, если он не пустой, если пустой то lastname..
Вопрос как написать запрос правильно ?

SELECT name AS `name` OR lastname FROM customer...

Comment: `COALESCE(name, lastname)`

Comment: а если не null столбец а просто пуст ?

Comment: `select if(name<>"", name, lastname) `

Comment: `COALESCE(NULLIF(name, ''), lastname)`

Comment: @Akina может, стоит написать ответ ради  nullif ? я когда-то про нее читал, а вспомнил только, когда ваш ответ увидел. вероятно, я не один такой :))

Comment: @splash58 Так по исполнению-то оно ничем не отличается от IF() или даже CASE. Смысл?

Comment: не знаю, я собственно, тут болтаюсь что-нить новенькое узнать иногда. Поэтому люблю ответы с редкоиспользуемыми функциями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если "пустой" означает значение `NULL`, то запрос может быть таким:

`SELECT IFNULL(name, lastname) AS name FROM customer...`

Если же "пустое" имя - это пустая строка (`''`) - то:

`SELECT IF(name = '', lastname, name) AS name FROM customer...`